# php simplexml object caching

Tags: php, xml, caching, rss

Consider the following function prototype for caching object from cached RSS(XML) feed:

```
function cacheObject($xml,$name,$age = 3600)
  { 
    // directory in which to store cached files
    $cacheDir = "cache/";
    // cache filename
    $filename = $cacheDir.$name;
    // default to fetch the file
    $cache = true;
    // but if the file exists, don't fetch if it is recent enough
    if (file_exists($filename))
    {
      $cache = (filemtime($filename) < (time()-$age));
    }
    // fetch the file if required
    if ($cache)
    {
      $item = $xml->channel->item;
      file_put_contents($filename,serialize($item));
      // update timestamp to now
      touch($filename);
    }
    // return the cache filename
    return unserialize(file_get_contents($filename));
  }
```

The function calls are as follows:

```
$urlD = "http://somerss.php";
    $xmlD = simplexml_load_file(cacheFetch($urlD,'cachedfeedD.xml',3600));
    $itemD = '';
    if($xmlD === FALSE)
        {$itemD = '';}
    else
        {$itemD = cacheObject($xmlD,'cacheobjectD',3600);}
 $urlM = "somerss2.php";
    $xmlM = simplexml_load_file(cacheFetch($urlM,'cachedfeedM.xml',3600));
    $itemM = '';
    if($xmlM ===  FALSE) 
        {$itemM = '';}
    else
        {$itemM = cacheObject($xmlM,'cacheobjectM',3600);}
```

I get the following error:

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' 
with message 'Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed' in C:\xampp\htdocs\sitefinal\cacheObject.php:20 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\sitefinal\cacheObject.php(20): serialize(Object(SimpleXMLElement))
```

Any help making this program to work is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, the [SimpleXMLElement](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) class, like [many built-in PHP objects, cannot be serialized](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php).

Instead, you could call the class method [asXML](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php) (which returns a valid XML string if you pass no parameters) and serialize this. You can then recreate the SimpleXMLElement class by calling [simplexml_load_string()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) on this string.

Comment: Could you give some code example of the procedure in this case, please

Comment: If the object can't be serialized, you're really only able to cache the response of the feed. Which I'd argue changes the question.

Answer (score 0):

Magpierss (free open source) is supposed to cache external xml files. I used it some years ago. You set the software a time frame to pull the xml file again. It worked well. Only problem I saw was that it kept pulling the xml file whether there was a frontend request for it or not which was using up the server. I think there might be a fix for that however. Good luck.